# How do I cancel my button:hover in css when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `.button:hover` thing in my css code, but I want that code to be canceled for five seconds when my button is pressed? My code is below.

```js
function myFunction(){
  var text = document.getElementById('input').value;
  var textArray = text.split(" ").sort();
  var output= document.getElementById('output');
  output.value = textArray.toString().replace(/,/g," ");
}

function maFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("output");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
}

/*function ok() {
  document.getElementById("copied").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
*/

/*function fadeOut(){
 location.href='index.html#open-modal';
 setTimeout(function () {
     location.href='index.html#modal-close';
     }, 1000);
}*/
```

```css
body {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: flex;
}

.form {
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    
}

 .input {
    height: 700px;
    width: 600px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 26px;
    resize: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #4CAF50;
    border-width: 2px;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.otput {
    height: 695px;
    width: 620px;
    outline: none;
    resize: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #4CAF50;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

 .output {
    height: 650px;
    width: 512px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 26px;
    resize: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.button {
    background: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 14px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 0 10px;
    /*margin-left: 1134px;*/
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
}

.speech-bubble {
    height: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
 position: relative;
 background: #4CAF50;
    border-radius: 1px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    display: none;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-left: 630px;
}

.speech-bubble:after {
    content: '';
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 50%;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border: 9px solid transparent;
 border-right-color: #4CAF50;
 border-left: 0;
 margin-top: -9px;
    margin-left: -9px;
}

.button:hover + .speech-bubble {
    transform: translateY(-690px);
    display: block;
}

.button:hover + .speech-bubble:after {
    display: block;
}

::selection {
  color: black;
  background: lightblue;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {
    width: 20px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888;
}


/*.modal-window {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.modal-window:target {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modal-window > div {
    width: 170px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    /*padding: 2rem;*/
    /*background: #fff;
    color: #333;
}

.modal-window .copy{
    font-size: 20px;
}*/
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>alphabetical order machine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
        <textarea class="input"  id="input" type="text" placeholder="type your text here" onchange="myFunction()" onkeyup="myFunction()"></textarea>

        <form class="otput">

        <textarea class="output" id="output" type="output" placeholder="your alphabetized text will appear here"></textarea>
        <input class="button" type='button' value="copy" onclick="maFunction()">
        
        <p class="speech-bubble">click to copy text</p>
        <!--p id="copied" class="copied"></p-->
        </form>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `class` on click and use it to set `display:none` for the speech buble .

possible example

```js
function myFunction(){
  var text = document.getElementById('input').value;
  var textArray = text.split(" ").sort();
  var output= document.getElementById('output');
  output.value = textArray.toString().replace(/,/g," ");
}

function maFunction(el) { //update : el
  el.classList.add('clicked');// update 
  var copyText = document.getElementById("output");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  setTimeout(  () => el.classList.remove('clicked'),5000);//Oups, needed : update to recover hover behavior after 5s
}

/*function ok() {
  document.getElementById("copied").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
*/

/*function fadeOut(){
 location.href='index.html#open-modal';
 setTimeout(function () {
     location.href='index.html#modal-close';
     }, 1000);
}*/
```

```css
body {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: flex;
}

.form {
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    
}

 .input {
    height: 700px;
    width: 600px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 26px;
    resize: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #4CAF50;
    border-width: 2px;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.otput {
    height: 695px;
    width: 620px;
    outline: none;
    resize: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #4CAF50;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

 .output {
    height: 650px;
    width: 512px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 26px;
    resize: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.button {
    background: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 14px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 0 10px;
    /*margin-left: 1134px;*/
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
}

.speech-bubble {
    height: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
 position: relative;
 background: #4CAF50;
    border-radius: 1px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    display: none;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-left: 630px;
}
.speech-bubble:after {
    content: '';
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 50%;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border: 9px solid transparent;
 border-right-color: #4CAF50;
 border-left: 0;
 margin-top: -9px;
    margin-left: -9px;
}

.button:hover + .speech-bubble {
    transform: translateY(-690px);
    display: block;
}

.button:hover + .speech-bubble:after {
    display: block;
}

.button.clicked + .speech-bubble {display:none}/* UPDATE HERE */
::selection {
  color: black;
  background: lightblue;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {
    width: 20px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888;
}


/*.modal-window {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.modal-window:target {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modal-window > div {
    width: 170px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    /*padding: 2rem;*/
    /*background: #fff;
    color: #333;
}

.modal-window .copy{
    font-size: 20px;
}*/
```

```html
<textarea class="input"  id="input" type="text" placeholder="type your text here" onchange="myFunction()" onkeyup="myFunction()"></textarea>

        <form class="otput">

        <textarea class="output" id="output" type="output" placeholder="your alphabetized text will appear here"></textarea>
        <input class="button" type='button' value="copy" onclick="maFunction(this)"><!-- update on onclick -->
        
        <p class="speech-bubble">click to copy text</p>
        <!--p id="copied" class="copied"></p-->
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class called `.clicked`, which contains the styling you want to see when the button is clicked. Then add the class to the button for 5 seconds.

```js
function clicked (button) {
  button.classList.add('clicked');
  setTimeout(
    () => button.classList.remove('clicked'),
    5000);
}
```

```css
button:hover.clicked {
  background-color: red;
}

button:hover.clicked + .speech-bubble {
  color: blue;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="m-4">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="clicked(this);">Sample Button</button>
  <p class="speech-bubble">click to copy text</p>
</div>
```